# no matching function for call to 'begin(int [n])'

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, compiler-errors, stdvector

Getting the error

```
no matching function for call to 'begin(int [n])'
```

I am using *vectors* and *array* and *set* but can't find out the reason for the error.
P.S. - I googled it but also couldn't find out anything relevant.
I tried debugging it but couldn't do it.
Here's my code!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int n, flag = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int a[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        int index1 = distance(begin(a), find(begin(a), end(a), 2));
        std::set<int> sa(a, a + n);
        std::vector<int> vec(sa.size());
        std::copy(sa.begin(), sa.end(), vec.begin());
        int arr[vec.size()];
        copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == a[j]) {
                    int index1 = distance(begin(a), find(begin(a), end(a), i));
                    int index2 = distance(begin(a), find(begin(a), end(a), j));
                    if (index1 < n && index2 < n) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag) { cout << "Truly Happy\n"; }
        else if (!flag) {
            cout << "Poor Chef\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **variable sized arrays**, which [*are not part of C++ standards*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), and you are using it in your code.

Use [std::vector<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of them. That means, change this

```
int a[n]; // to ----------------------------> std::vector<int> a(n);
```

and this line

```
std::set<int> sa(a, a + n); // to ----------> std::set<int> sa(a.begin(), a.end());
```

also

```
int arr[vec.size()]; // to -----------------> std::vector<int> arr(vec.size());
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr); // to ---> copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr.begin());
```

then your code will work.

However,

1. Here

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  scanf("%d", &a[i]);     }
   ```

   it looks like you are trying to have an array filling elements from
   `0, 1, 2,... , n-1`. This could be easily done by
   [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota). That means, the following is equivalent to the `for loop`, which you wrote.

   ```
   std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
   ```
2. Secondly, you are doing so many copying, which does not look like a
   good algorithm. Especially, coping with the *set* `sa` and again coping it back to another vector(`vec`). This is definitely, not you
   want I guess.
3. You do not need to use `std::find` on vector/ array `a`. Since it is
   in sorted order the relation between *array index* and *array
   element* is of difference `1`, make use of this information to find
   the index.

---

**PS**: Do not use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`, see [this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and 
[using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is not a good coding practices.